# Parsing and splitting a String 

Tags: java, string, split

I want to format one string "Event"

When I print it. it gives me result like :

```
When : Wed 18 Apr 2012 04:30 to Wed 18 Apr 2012 06:30  

Who: test@gmail.com

Event status : Confirmed.
```

It gives answers in this 3 category.

`Who,when and Event Status`.

But i want these three results in a separate string .How to format these string so that i ll get it seperately

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`String[] parts = resultString.split("\n+");`

This will split your string by enters (`\n+` means one or more new line symbol) and store parts in `parts` array

Comment: You probably wanted `"\n+"`, `*` means 0 or more symbols, while `+` means 1 or more.

Comment: You can loop on parts and check which string it is using startsWith(String prefix) method of string. for example you can check if firsrt part is the `When` part: `for(String part : parts){ if(part.startsWith("When")){ do something for When} }`

Answer (score 0):

If there are single new line characters in between the 3 lines then use this :

`String splitLine[] = String.split("\\r?\\n");`

Answer (score 0):

Split the content based on `\r\n`, which treats as new line.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, you have as input the string:

```
When : Wed 18 Apr 2012 04:30 to Wed 18 Apr 2012 06:30  

Who: test@gmail.com

Event status : Confirmed.
```

And you want to get as output three strings (or an array of strings) containing respectively:

```
whenString="Wed 18 Apr 2012 04:30 to Wed 18 Apr 2012 06:30"
whoString="test@gmail.com"
eventString="Confirmed."
```

If this is the case, then

```
String[] lines = source.split("\n+");

int index = lines[0].indexOf("When"); 
String whenString = lines[0].substring(index+7);

index = lines[1].indexOf("Who"); 
String whoString = lines[1].substring(index+5);

index = lines[2].indexOf("Event status"); 
String whoString = lines[2].substring(index+15);
```